# Restrict when users can log into SQL Server Management Studio by day/time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

We have several users in our database that we only want to allow them access via their user between certain static times of the day, and only on certain days, I can't see anything in the user properties to do this so guessing it cant be done, just wanted to check if anyone on here knows of any way of doing it before I put this idea to bed?

Answer (score 3):

Create a couple of SQL Server agent jobs that grant/revoke privileges, then schedule these to run at the appropriate times.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a [`Logon Trigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) that checks the login name and datetime and calls `ROLLBACK` if needed.

You would likely still need a scheduled job to handle (e.g. `kill`) already open connections belonging to these users at the cut off points when their access expires though.